# Vector failing to initialize in VSCode, but works in XCode for Mac

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to initialize the below vector in VSCode but getting the error message "non-aggregate type 'vector' cannot be initialized with an initializer list". I have read quite a few of the previous threads stating "-std=c++11" needs to be added into the args section of the tasks.json file, which has not resolved the issue for me. I also have Xcode installed on my computer, and my script runs without any issues there. Does someone know whats causing the issue in VSCode? I'm required to use VSCode for school which is the only reason I need it resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`vector<int> test_vec = {63, 31, 3, 6, 309, 32, 9380, 7};`

Comment: VS Code is an IDE that can work with many different compilers. Which one are you using? What compilation flags do you have set?

Answer (score 0):

The specific wording of the error message suggest you are compiling with Clang.

This error is indeed consistent with a pre c++11 compilation. Adding the compiler flag `-std=c++11` (or higher) should fix your issue.

That being said, it is likely that you did not put the flag in the right place.

Given the information you provided, you should check [VSCode documentation on how to configure c++ with Clang on Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)